# Using a query to delete dates a number of days older than a given date

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using a query only I am looking for a way to have the delete query pull the date in the field I labeled `Called On` and only delete the records when they become 2 days or older.

For example:

- `6/10/19` is todays `Called On` date
- I want to delete any records that are `6/7/19`
- I want the Query to be able to skip the `6/9/19` and `6/8/19`.
- I want the query to always take the `Called On` Date and Delete the values that match my criteria.

I'm kind of at a stand still as I want it to delete the dates 2 days older than the date specified, but it is only deleting 2-day-old records.

Comment: Could you provide examples of input data (list of dates), parameter `Called On` date, and desired behaviour (list of dates to delete, list of dates to be kept)? Also it is better to provide your sql query text, that you are running?

Comment: Why delete records and not just apply filter? Edit question to post the attempted SQL statement.

Comment: This is where I am at a stand still I never have used SQL before so I am having an issue trying to write the code to complete it all together. But what I am looking for is If my "Called On" date was 6/9/19 and todays actual date is 6/13/19 I want it to delete from that 3rd day back and so on so it wouldnt delete 6/12,6/11,6/10 it would delete 6/9 and back until all of that data was deleted

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you refer to as *"today's `Called On` date"* is the latest date held by the `Called On` field<sup>1</sup>, then the query might be:

```sql
delete from YourTable where [Called On] < DMax("[Called On]","YourTable")-2
```

Change all references of `YourTable` to the name of your table.

---

<sup>1</sup> presumably this is not simply today's date, else the query would be straightforward:

```sql
delete from YourTable where [Called On] < Date()-2
```